# How to reduce tables with different sizes?

Tags: r

```
data(iris)
table1<-iris[,-5]
a<-list()
a[[1]]<-table1[1,]
a[[2]]<-table1[2,-2]
Reduce("+",a)
```

doesnt work!!! How can I fix this? sum tables with different extents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create a `vector` of intersecting names and get the `sum`

```
nm1 <- Reduce(intersect,lapply(a, names))
Reduce(`+`, lapply(a, `[`, nm1))
#  Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1           10          2.8         0.4
```

---

If we need the `sum` of all

```
nm2 <- Reduce(union, lapply(a, names))
Reduce(`+`,  lapply(a, function(x) { x[setdiff(nm2, names(x))] <- 0; x}))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#1           10         4.9          1.6         0.2
```

Comment: This works very good to make a sum of the intersection values, but how can I do that if I have a lot of different combinations and I want to compute the sum of all?

Comment: @VivianRibeiro  For those cases, use the `setdiff` and get those elements that are not intersecting and assign it to NA

Answer (score 2):

you can try summing the columns of the merged tables:

```
colSums(Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, all=TRUE), a), na.rm=TRUE)
#Sepal.Length Petal.Length  Petal.Width  Sepal.Width 
#        10.0          2.8          0.4          3.5
```